# Rotate cell text in a PdfGrid using Syncfusion

Tags: c#, syncfusion

How can I rotate a cell value in a PDF grid header?

I do not want to rotate the graphics.

Is there a way to rotate the cell text in PdfGrid without using Graphics.RotateTransform?

I have the following code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dsourceII.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    Main2dGrid.Headers[0].Cells[j+1].Value = dsourceII.Rows[j][1].ToString();
}

Main2dGrid.Headers[0].Cells[0].Value = "";
Main2dGrid.Headers[0].Cells[Main2dGrid.Columns.Count-1].Value = "";
foreach (PdfGridCell Cell in Main2dGrid.Headers[0].Cells)
{
    // Here I need to rotate all the cell value in Header[0], but not my grid

    Cell.StringFormat = STRINGformatRight;
    Cell.Style.Font = Tahoma;
    Cell.Style.Borders.All = PENWhite;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can rotate the PdfGrid headers alone using a rotate transform with graphics using BeginCellEvent. Please refer to the knowledge base link for more information,

*https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6179/how-to-draw-rotated-headers-in-a-pdf-grid-using-c-and-vb-net*

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Sorry, the webpage might be temporarily down or an error might have occurred while handling your request. We are working on it. Please reload this page later."*

Comment: Can you expand on your answer so it is self-contained (external resources are only for supplementary purposes)?